# How to return the first element of certain lines in a list

Tags: python, list, sorting

How to I return the first element of the first and last line in a python program.

For example,

```
Bahrain,1701575,0.0368,60403,760,Asia
Timor-Leste,1318445,0.0196,25326,14870,Asia
Cyprus,1207359,0.0073,-8784,9240,Asia
Bhutan,771608,0.0112,8516,38117,Asia
Macao,649335,0.0139,8890,30781,Asia
Maldives,540544,0.0181,9591,300,Asia
```

how do I return Bahrain and Maldives.

I'm quite stuck on where to start.

I've sorted the countries based on descending order of population and I now need to return the names of the countries with the smaller and largest population

Comment: If you only want to return the min and the max, why are you sorting everything instead of just getting the min and the max?

Comment: In what kind of data type do you have that data?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple method:

1. Read all lines from the file into a list with [`readlines`](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/io.html#io.IOBase.readlines).
2. Select the first and the last lines from this list.
3. Extract the first element of each of these two lines: `line.split(',')[0]`.
4. Done!

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```py
data = """
Bahrain,1701575,0.0368,60403,760,Asia
Timor-Leste,1318445,0.0196,25326,14870,Asia
Cyprus,1207359,0.0073,-8784,9240,Asia
Bhutan,771608,0.0112,8516,38117,Asia
Macao,649335,0.0139,8890,30781,Asia
Maldives,540544,0.0181,9591,300,Asia
"""

data = data.strip() # remove whitespace
data = data.split("\n") # split rows
data = [sublist.split(",") for sublist in data] # split every row

print(data[0][0])
print(data[-1][0])
```

Prints:

```
Bahrain
Maldives
```

This code stores `data` to a string, and then turns that string into a matrix. Then, it finds the first element of the first and last lines. However, you could index any piece of data from this matrix.

However, if you *just* wanted to get the first item of the first and last lists, then you could just do:

```py
data = """
Bahrain,1701575,0.0368,60403,760,Asia
Timor-Leste,1318445,0.0196,25326,14870,Asia
Cyprus,1207359,0.0073,-8784,9240,Asia
Bhutan,771608,0.0112,8516,38117,Asia
Macao,649335,0.0139,8890,30781,Asia
Maldives,540544,0.0181,9591,300,Asia
"""

data = data.strip().split("\n") # remove whitespace and split into rows

print(data[0].split(",")[0])
print(data[-1].split(",")[0])
```

Which prints the same thing.